# EKS cluster not accessible from an EC2 instance in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, role-based-access-control

I've created an EKS cluster with an IAM role and I'm trying to access the cluster from my CI build agent which is present in a different account.
My CI build ec2 instance is not being to able identify the EKS cluster when I attach an Instance profile and a trust relationship with the role used to create the EKS cluster.
But when I go with User authentication, I'm getting the expected output.
I want it to be accessible with the IAM role instead of the IAM User.
Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.
Note: The EKS cluster is created using Terraform with an Assume role authentication.

Comment: it would be really helpful, if you could share code snippet of terraform

Comment: what is the error that you are facing ?? is it something like ""error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)."? If yes, probably solution provided in below link might work for you. Link : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.